# How to create jsonb structures from function variables?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have some ugly, but working, (plpg)SQL:

```
CONCAT('{"mtlogonsuccess":{"ts":"', now_json, '"}}')::jsonb);
```

(This is within `VALUES()` within an `INSERT INTO`, within a trigger function.)

I'm not happy with this approach, as I have some nested objects to create, which have many variables.

Is there a better way of creating a `jsonb` from arbitrary function variables?  (I'm looking for string interpolation but have not found it.)

---

Update: Here's the requested insert statement, from within the function.

```
    -- Pre-calculate the ISO timestamp.
    SELECT to_json(now())#>>'{}' INTO STRICT now_json;
    ...
    -- and send the success message
    INSERT INTO outbound(ts, dt, mt, site, channel, messageid, payload)
            VALUES(NOW(), 'SERVER', NEW.mt, mtlogon->>'site', mtlogon->>'channel', 'UNKNOWN',
                   CONCAT('{"mtlogonsuccess":{"ts":"', now_json, '"}}')::jsonb);
```

Comment: There are many JSON and JSONB functions in Postgres, but you're going to have to give us more context. Can you show us your full `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Charlieface I've added the insert statement.  This insert statement isn't much of a problem.  I want to add new insert statements with much larger chunks of JSON.  I'm looking for a method to avoid the messy `CONCAT()` growing to 19+ arguments.

Comment: Well there's the ` jsonb_build_object` and `jsonb_object` functions which could help, but I still don't know exactly what you want. You've shown an `INSERT` but then said that's *not* what you want. How about you show us an example of what you're trying to achieve, your attempt so far

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html was what I was missing.

Comment: It is pretty weird to go out of your way to convert the json to text with `#>>`, only to manually add the double quotes back on later.

Comment: @jjanes now_json is used as a string in other places.  I should call it now_string instead.